# Gtkmm ListStore, how to catch that value in one of the rows was changed?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I need to redraw image when some value in table will change. I want to know how to catch a changing of values in table.
I found signal_row_changed, but it give const Gtk::TreeModel::Path& and const Gdk::TreeModel::iterator&.
And when I do something like this:

```
...
void PrMainWindow::redraw(){...}
...
nRefTree->signal_row_changed().connect
    (sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                  &PrMainWindow::redraw));
```

where nRefTree - Glib::Refptr, compiler give me the error.
But, if I do

```
void PrMainWindow::redraw(
    const Gtk::TreeModel::Path& path,
    const Gtk::TreeModel::iterator& iter)
{...}
```

than it works, but I don't need these references because this function can be called from other places and without these parameters.

Maybe there is some other signal for this or method for cutting useless parameters? Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is calling redraw from the connected signal fun:

```
nRefTree->signal_row_changed().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &PrMainWindow::MyChangedSignal));

void PrMainWindow::MyChangedSignal(const Gtk::TreeModel::Path& path, const Gtk::TreeModel::iterator& iter)
{
    ...
    redraw();
}
```

so `redraw()`can be called from other places too.

---

The tricky way I can imagine (not tested) is:

- Use `gobj()` to get the underlying `GtkListStore*`
- `GtkListStore` implements `GtkTreeModel` so all of its methods are available.

What I'm supposing is that you can connect your callback to GtkTreeModel' "row-changed" signal. This callback uses pointers instead of references, so can call it from other places without parameters.

Comment: It looks...strange, but I think, it'll work. Thank you!